# General notation for indicating the last digit of a given power

Tags: notation, modular-arithmetic

Let's say I wanted to state, for example, what's the last digit of a power with a base of a number ending with 4 as its last digit.

Casually, I'd just write it down as:

$$...4^{2n}=...6 \\ ...4^{2n+1}=...4$$

where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $...$ denotes an unspecified sequence of digits.

However, is there a way to jot it down in a more formal manner?

Would, for instance, the following be an acceptable notation:

$$(\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n 10^ia_{j} + 4)^{2n}= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n 10^ib_{j} +6$$
$$(\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n 10^ia_{j} + 4)^{2n+1}= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n 10^ib_{j} +4$$
where $a,b,i,j,n \in \mathbb{N}$? What do you think?

Thank you in advance for any opinions or even suggestions (for a "neater" way to represent the aforementioned concept, if there is one).

Answer (score 1):

Use modulo notation:
$$\ldots4^{2n}\equiv6\pmod{10} \quad\text{and } \ldots4^{2n+1}\equiv4\pmod{10}.$$

Comment: Ok, thank you, but what if I'd like to get rid of the ellipsis entirely? Also, although I do look for as many alternatives as possible, it'd be nice to know if the notation I orginally used is correct or not as I'm a newbie to the sigma notation so I can't evaluate it on my own.

Comment: You could say that if $x\equiv4\pmod{10}$ then $x^{2n}\equiv6\pmod{10}$ and $x^{2n+1}\equiv4\pmod{10}$.

Comment: Oh, it's that easy, I see it now. :) Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: An alternative might be to say $\forall k\in \mathbb N \text{ and } n \in \mathbb N^+ , \exists m \in \mathbb N: (10k+4)^{2n} = 10m+6$ etc